# trying to show the same content in page and also in fancybox

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fancybox

Im trying to fill my articles with content that is coming from the database.

I have my articles with: title, image, date, content **and with a link (read more) to open a fancybox** that will show the same content of this article but in the fancybox.

So I have my div `id="show-container"` that corresponds to the div that shows the content in fancybox.

This div have display:none in css and it only appears when the user click in the link with #show href and class="fancybox", here:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a>
```

But I want to show the same content in fancybox so Im fill this "show" div with the same info that I put in the article.

My articles are working fine, each article is with right name,image and content.

**But when I click to open the fancybox** of each article all the fancyboxs **have the same content**, that is the content of my first article.

Anyone there know how I can fix this?

```
$readPost = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4");
$readPost->execute();
$folder  = '../images/';
while ($readPostResult  = $readPost->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

echo '<article id="loop-news">';
      echo '<img src="'.$folder.$readPostResult['thumb'].'" title="'.$readPostResult['title'].'"/>';
      echo '<h2>';
        echo '<a href="#show" class="x" >'.$readPostResult['title'].'</a><br />';
      echo '</h2>';
      echo '<p>'.$readPostResult['content'].'<a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a></p>';

      echo '<div id="show-container">';
        echo '<div id="show">';
          echo '<h2>'.$readPostResult['title'].'</h2>';
          echo '<br />';
          echo '<img src="'.$folder.$readPostResult['thumb'].'" title="'.$readPostResult['title'].'"/>';
          echo '<p>'.$readPostResult['content'].'<br /></p>';
          echo '<a class="button" href="index.html">Back</a>';
       echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
echo '</article>';
}

?>
```

I think I need to pass the id of each news when I click in my a href:

```
echo '<p>'.$readPostResult['content'].'<a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a></p>';
```

Do you know How I can do that?? Because Im already using "#show#" in my link to open the fancybox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use class for css instead of id

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem still remains!

Comment: Thank you MYoussef the main problem was really that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your ID values are meant to be unique to the element. Because you're generate the content in a loop, you will have multiple duplicate ID values in your elements. Try changing it to this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($readPostResult  = $readPost->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    echo '<article id="loop-news-' . $i . '">';
    echo '<img src="'.$folder.$readPostResult['thumb'].'" title="'.$readPostResult['title'].'"/>';
    echo '<a href="#show" id="info-' . $i . '"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>';
    echo '<h2>';
    echo '<a href="#show" class="x" >'.$readPostResult['title'].'</a><br />';
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<span>'.date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($readPostResult['date'])).'</span>';
    echo '<p>'.lmWord($readPostResult['content'],270).'<a class="fancybox" href="#show-' . $i . '" id="showFancy-' . $i . '">Read more</a></p>';

    echo '<div id="show-container-' . $i . '">';
    echo '<div id="show-' . $i . '">';
      echo '<h2>'.$readPostResult['title'].'</h2>';
      echo '<br />';
      echo '<img src="'.$folder.$readPostResult['thumb'].'" title="'.$readPostResult['title'].'"/>';
      echo '<p>'.$readPostResult['content'].'<br /></p>';
      echo '<a class="button" href="index.html">Back</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</article>';

    ++$i;
}
```

You'll notice, I've created an `$i` variable outside the while loop, and it appends the value of `$i` to all your ID elements. Once at the end of the loop, it will increase `$i` by 1, so that all your IDs in your loop will be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that with that method my articles are without the format I have in css, because I dont have in css format to #loop-news-1 and #loop-news-2 and so on!

Comment: @OzzC You need to change your CSS to use a class for your design, instead of IDs. IDs have to be unique, means: they must only appear ONCE on your page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thorsten, but Im trying to convert the ids for class´s but it seems that fancybox dont work with classes. If in my link to open the fancybox (<a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a>) I use href=".show" and then change in my div id ="show" to div class="show", the fancybox dont opens!

Comment: Thank you for your answer thorsten! Your answer its correct, I use that method, but instead of creating a new variable $i, Im using my id of news, like this: echo '<article id="loop-news-' . $readNews['id'] . '">'; and it worked fine, but I accepted the answer before yours, because it was first than yours and it was also correct! But, thank you very much for your answer and explanation!